# How to post a Json object for an object of a class with an overloaded constructor?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a view in my web application that contain some listboxes etc. I want to post the values of these elements to my MVC controller. In order to do so, I created a class that contains all neccessary data. This class has two constructors: one without any parameters (creates an empty object) and one with two parameters (pre-populates the object with data from a DB).

Now, when I create the Json object according to the class, it gets sent, but the server responds with error 500 and tells me that a *System.MissingMethodException* occured because there has not been defined a parameterless constructor for this object. Well... there surely is one, but obviously the other one (the "parameterful") gets called.

Is there a way to tell my application which constructor to use when deserializing  the Json string into an object?

Comment: You need to show the model with the constructors (it should work fine)

Comment: Yes... in fact it *does*. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I overlooked one of the sub-objects within my object, this class indeed only had a constructor *with* parameters. Everything works now.

BTW: It would be way more helpful if the error messages would cleary state *which* object it is talking about. The same applies for error messages concerning uninitialized objects.